# How to open Microsoft serial monitor output panel in my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I open the other extension's panel in my extension?

The microsoft serial monitor extension is very excellent. I want to open the monitor output panel in my extension using the command. How can I get it?

I didn't not find the API like the `vscode.window.panels`. I want to get the microsoft panel and show it or a command can show the outputPanel.